How to handle non-bazel external dependencies?
My embedded development environment has been setup with Bazel.
With Bazel 6.5.x and workspaces I'm able to cross build everything i want.
Due to reasons I want to migrate to Bazel modules.
Direct bazel dependencies and project files, etc. have been migrates easily.
But currently, I'm stuck with my projects external dependencies.
With Bazel workspaces I could do:
http_archive(
    name = "cmsis_device_g0",
    url = "https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/cmsis_device_g0/archive/refs/tags/v1.4.4.zip",
    strip_prefix = "cmsis-device-g0-1.4.4",
    sha256 = "c60d9f8478f356db0461d797d573d82baebe62695acea5944128f242a7a71fc6",
    build_file = "//thirdparty/stm32:stm32_cmsis_device.BUILD",
)
http_archive(
    name = "stm32g0xx_hal_driver",
    url = "https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/stm32g0xx_hal_driver/archive/refs/tags/v1.4.6.zip",
    strip_prefix = "stm32g0xx-hal-driver-1.4.6",
    sha256 = "1098b8b816047063bed5fb3abfc2e5a15e16d6696a279b59b9a0be5d850d2f09",
    build_file = "//thirdparty/stm32:stm32_hal_driver.BUILD",
)

Add them as dependency to my project and build.
But with Bazel modules, I can't seem to find the proper method or explanation (or at least I don't understand it) for handling non-Bazel dependencies.

With MODULE.bazel, you can still do something similar in your MODULE.bazel file:
http_archive = use_repo_rule(
    "@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive",
)

http_archive(
    name = "cmsis_device_g0",
    url = "https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/cmsis_device_g0/archive/refs/tags/v1.4.4.zip",
    strip_prefix = "cmsis-device-g0-1.4.4",
    sha256 = "c60d9f8478f356db0461d797d573d82baebe62695acea5944128f242a7a71fc6",
    build_file = "//thirdparty/stm32:stm32_cmsis_device.BUILD",
)

